# Find the limit $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{3\theta + \tan \theta}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Given problem
$$\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{3\theta + \tan \theta}$$

I got to 
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta}{3\theta \cos \theta + \sin \theta}$$

Now I'm lost. Any advice on how to be more efficient?

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's rule? If yes that should solve it already before the rewriting.

Comment: This is the start of my first Calculus course I am not familiar but I will surely look it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** : divide both side to $\theta $ and note that $$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { \theta  }  }{ \theta  }  } =1\\ \lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \tan { \theta  }  }{ \theta  }  } =1\\ $$

Comment: So is $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\cos \theta}{\theta} = 1$

Comment: it is wrong conclusion,plug $\theta =0$ in the limit what will you get?

Comment: it comes from $\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \tan { \theta  }  }{ \theta  }  } =\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { \theta  }  }{ \theta  } \frac { 1 }{ \cos { \theta  }  }  } =1$

Comment: @AlexanderJohn no, that is wrong. This limit does not exist because the numerator converges to 1 and the denominator to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You can write it as:
$$
\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\sin \theta\left(\frac{3 \theta}{\sin \theta}+\frac{1}{\cos \theta} \right)}=
\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{3 \theta}{\sin \theta}+\frac{1}{\cos \theta} }
$$

can you do from these?

Answer (score 1):

Since both $\sin\theta$ and $3\theta + \tan \theta$ tend to $0$ as $\theta\to0$, we use L'Hôptial's rule

$$\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin \theta}{3\theta + \tan \theta}=\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\cos \theta}{3 + \sec^2 \theta} = \frac{1}{3+1} = \frac14.$$

Comment: I can't see any reason for a downvte. It is the correct application of L'Hopital's rule. So +1

Comment: @miracle173  Thanks for your upvote.  In fact, I had made a mistake in the first sentence, so I corrected it.